# Trouble animating RadialGradientBrush in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to animate a [`RadialGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush.aspx) in my application. I get the super helpful exception:

`Additional information: 'System.Windows.Style' value cannot be assigned to property 'Style' of object 'System.Windows.Controls.Border'. '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1).[0].(2)'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Style' in markup file 'Eng.Modules.Core;component/system/grid/systemgridview.xaml' Line 252 Position 51.`

I know it's something wrong with the indirect property targeting or partial path qualification in my `DoubleAnimation`'s `Storyboard.TargetProperty` attribute. Any ideas?

```
<Border>
  <Border.Resources>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="SomeBrush">
      <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="Gold" Offset="1" />
      </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
  </Border.Resources>
  <Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SomeBrush}" />
          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SomeStoryBoard">
              <Storyboard>
                <!-- RIGHT HERE -->
                <DoubleAnimation
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                  From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                  AutoReverse="True" />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SomeStoryBoard" />
          </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are setting the background to a gradient brush in your `DataTrigger`. Because this gets applied later, the animation won't be able to find the brush (hence the cryptic error about not finding a dependency property). So the first thing I did was set the border's background to the brush manually, rather than in the trigger.

The second problem was how you were setting up the target property. You don't need to use the parenthesis syntax- it works just fine as follows: `Background.GradientStops[0].Offset`.

With these changes the border animates perfectly; here is the final mark-up:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Gold" Offset="1" />
            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SomeStoryBoard">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <!-- RIGHT HERE -->
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Offset"
                                      From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"
                                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                      AutoReverse="True" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SomeStoryBoard" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Comment: Why remove the GradientBrush from the DataTrigger? The OP may require the Brush ONLY to appear on the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

My Answer as per the comments in the code sample.

I've removed the MultiDataTrigger from my first post, as I can't get this working myself with bound collections. I may have to ask this to see if anyone has an answer to the issue.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
            <!-- Don't use a ControlTemplate. This destroys your control structure, 
which doesn't make sense if all you want to do is animate the background. -->
            <Style x:Key="MyAnimatedFeatureStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="GoldRadialGradientBrush">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Gold" Offset="1" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False" x:Key="SomeStoryBoard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Offset" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Your primary binding condition. Whatever this may be. -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSOMTHINGSET}" Value="true" >
                    <!-- The Background is here in the setter, because we only want the background colored and animated on the binding condition. -->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GoldRadialGradientBrush}" />
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BorderStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource SomeStoryBoard}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BorderStoryBoard" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyAnimatedFeatureStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: On a second look at the issue, I can't get the MultiDataTrigger to work as it should depending on whether the bound item is already visible or not. One will fail with the Exception and the other will work. Swapping the Conditions around changes how this works, flips which one fails with the other. This does stand as an answer if used with a single DataTrigger though.

Comment: I've proposed the question in getting it working with MvvM.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181222/datatrigger-to-start-a-storyboard-within-an-itemscontrol-on-a-deep-binding-prope

Answer (score 0):

I actually developed a solution to the problem just as Charlie posted his. It looks like we came up with close to the same thing. Just posting mine for reference:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
              <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="GoldRadialGradientBrush">
                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                  <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="Gold" Offset="1" />
                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
              </RadialGradientBrush>
              <Storyboard x:Key="SomeStoryBoard">
                <DoubleAnimation
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].Offset"
                  From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                  AutoReverse="True" />
              </Storyboard>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Grid>
              <Border Background="{StaticResource GoldRadialGradientBrush}">
                <Border.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                          <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BorderStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource SomeStoryBoard}" />
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                          <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BorderStoryBoard" />
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                      </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
                </Border.Style>
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```