# Animating brush of GeometryDrawing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

I'm attempting to animate the mouseover of a Rectangle so that the gradient for a GeometryDrawing under the rectangle changes colour.

However when I do so, I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Drawing.(0).(1)[0].(2)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.
```

The code that I'm using is below:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Width="{Binding ElementName=ParentControl, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=ParentControl, Path=Height}">
        <Rectangle.Resources>
        </Rectangle.Resources>
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Drawing.(GeometryDrawing.Brush).(RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#486A71" Duration="0:0:0.5"></ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Drawing.(GeometryDrawing.Brush).(RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#485A71" Duration="0:0:0.5" FillBehavior="Stop"></ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <DrawingBrush>
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="2,0">
                                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                                            <LineSegment Point="200,0"></LineSegment>
                                            <LineSegment Point="200,7"></LineSegment>
                                            <LineSegment Point="185,20"></LineSegment>
                                            <LineSegment Point="200,33"></LineSegment>
                                            <LineSegment Point="200,40"></LineSegment>
                                            <LineSegment Point="2,40"></LineSegment>
                                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0, 0.5" Center="0, 0.5" RadiusX="0.90" RadiusY="0.6">
                                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#485A71" Offset="0" x:Name="GradientStop0"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#687F9F" Offset="1" x:Name="GradientStop1"></GradientStop>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Thickness="2" Brush="#374C6A" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

I understand that I need to sort out the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` attribute's value, however I'm still learning WPF so I don't quite know how to fix this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I feel a fool! Looks like I missed out one property when referencing the Gradient!

I also found out that you don't need to use the parenthesis when finding the property:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Drawing.Brush.GradientStops[0].Color" To="#486A71" Duration="0:0:0.5"></ColorAnimation>
```

I got the hints from this answer: [Trouble animating RadialGradientBrush in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539910/trouble-animating-radialgradientbrush-in-wpf?rq=1)